# Any way to 'identify' <P> tags in html?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website and out of curiousty, I was wondering if there was any practical way to identify p tags. I'll give you an example

```
p {
    font-family: 'Amatic';
    font-size: 36px;
```

In css, this means that all

tags have that font color and that size. But say, if I wanted to make it so that it only applies to that

tag and not all the global ones. For example

```
p 1 {
    font-family: 'Amatic';
    font-size: 36px;
p 2 {
    font-family: 'Comic sans';
    font-size: 36px;
```

Would there be any way?

(Yes, I put comic sans in there on purpose <3 )

Thanks!,
CMNatic

Comment: Give it a class, id, more specific selector. There are many ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use id and classes.
**A CLASS EXAMPLE**

```
<p class="one">This is a paragraph</p>
<p class="two">This is another paragrah</p>
```

and then in css use .class to select the element

```
p.one { font-family: 'Amatic'; font-size: 36px; }
p.two { font-family: 'Comic sans'; font-size: 36px; }
```

You must see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp) page.

Comment: @putvande +1 but please don't link to *w3fools*

Comment: @putvande Why did you hate w3schools I think it's great for beginners?

Comment: @FaizAhmed beginners are the most sensible learners and tend to blindly follow with a deeper understanding all the new stuff. w3schools are a self-driven website with a really huge amount of technical inaccuracy in their articles and examples. W3fools have recently removed some (they have fixed) but there's still an abyss or issues over there. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) on the other hand is really a precious resource of informations and the best part is that it's constantly maintained and reviewed by the community (just like SO ;)).

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Next time I'll use MDN ;)

Comment: @FaizAhmed for example talking about Community driven websites, go fix this CSS line: `p.tow` to `p.two`

Answer (score 0):

Apply a class to the p tag

```
<p class="pclass">test</p>
<style>
p.pclass
{
    font-family: 'Amatic';
    font-size: 36px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML, add an ID or a class. I.E.

```
<p id="p1">First paragraph</p>

<p class="red">Second paragraph</p>
```

The following CSS rules will apply to any p element with the ID of p1 (note the #)

```
p#1{
    ...
}
```

And these CSS rules will apply to any p element with the class of red (note the dot):

```
p.red {
    ...
}
```

IDs should be unique. Class names can be duplicated. For example, anywhere you want a red background, you could just give it a class of red. And then do:

```
.red{
    background-color: red;
}
```

This will apply to all elements with the class "red". The earlier example would only apply to p elements with the class "red".